# Heroku shows Whitelabel Error Page but not on localhost

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a Spring boot application with PostgreSQL. The app run very well on localhost with all the data from the PostgreSQL. I have successful upload the app to Heroku and migrated the database to Heroku PostgreSQL. The problem is when I click some of the links that retrieve data from PostgreSQL shows a **White Error page**. But on localhost every thing works fine.

[image]

Below is the Controller that link to the White Error Page.

```
@Controller
public class MahubiriController {
@Autowired
private MisaleRepository misaleRepository;

@GetMapping("/masomo/somolaleo")
    public String masomoAngalia(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("masomoYote", misaleRepository.findAllOrderByDateDesc() );
        return "masomo";     
} }
```

Below is the repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface MisaleRepository extends JpaRepository <Misale, String> {

@Query(value ="SELECT * FROM misale ORDER BY date DESC" , nativeQuery = true)
public List<Misale> findAllOrderByDateDesc();
 }
```

Below is the Entity for the particular object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "misale")
public class Misale {

     @Id
     @Column(name ="date")
     private String date;

     @Lob
     @Column(name ="first_reading", columnDefinition="text")
     private String firstReading;

     @Lob
     @Column(name ="second_reading", columnDefinition="text")
     private String secondReading;

     // Constructors, getter and setters

}
```

Below is the Query used to create the particular table on Postgresql

```
 CREATE TABLE misale(date VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
 first_reading TEXT NOT NULL,
 second_reading TEXT,gospel TEXT NOT NULL);
```

What could possibly be wrong on Heroku to lead to a **White Error Page** and not on a local host.

**Update** :

After implementing the Exception handling as suggested by @ krishnkant jaiswal, I receive message "Unable to access lob str…le to access lob stream" as below.

```
     timestamp  "2021-04-03T01:26:43.791+00:00"
     message    "Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream"
     details    "uri=/masomo/somolaleo"
```

Comment: You had to handle the exception and return the full stack error. Other wise it is very hard to debug.

I had seen the similar error what happening because I was trying to store larger data in string.(I your case it can be entirely different). You can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66763315/13046620

Comment: Likewise @krishnkantjaiswal I have stored large data with migration now I want to retrive them I get the White Error Message. let me implement the exception handling as you have suggested ans see.

Comment: Thanks @krishnkantjaiswal, With the help of the exception handling as you have suggested, I final solved the error as posted on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Exception handling and a long research, On my side it shows that you cannot use

```
 @Lob and @Column(columnDefinition="text")
```

So I had to remove @Lob and leave @Column(columnDefinition="text")

```
 @Column(columnDefinition="text")
```

Now I cloud retrieve the data from PostgreSQL without error.

Hope it might help someone else in future.